# What is the correct way to read the value from a date field in Xpages using SSJS

Tags: date, vector, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a date field in a notes document and need to read the value using ssjs.
if the field contains a value I can read it using

```
doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray[0]
```

but if the date field is empty the code will return an error.

so my question is 
how do I read a date field correctly using SSJS so that it does not return an error if it is empty and return a date value if there is a date value in the field

I am hoping for a solution without the need of a try/catch.

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var item:NotesItem =doc.getFirstItem("ItemName");
if (item== null) {
    dateVar=now;
} else {
    dateVar=doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the Item only contains a single DateTime, never multiple values and never DateRanges, adminfd's answer should work.

Otherwise it's more complex, as you will see from looking at `Document.getItemValueDateTimeArray()` in OpenNTF Domino API. The code (albeit Java) from M5 is appended below.

Bear in mind also that recycling `doc` or `item` will not recycle the resulting DateTime object. If you're getting DateTimes in a loop, you'll need to use `validDominoBase.recycle(dateVar)`, where validDominoBase is any Domino object that has not yet been recycled.

```
@Override
    public Vector<org.openntf.domino.Base<?>> getItemValueDateTimeArray(final String name) {        // cf. DateRange.java
        checkMimeOpen();
        boolean mayBeMime = true;
        Vector<org.openntf.domino.Base<?>> vGIV = null; // see below
        try {
            Vector<?> v = getDelegate().getItemValueDateTimeArray(name);
            mayBeMime = false;
            if (v == null || v.size() == 0)
                return (Vector<org.openntf.domino.Base<?>>) v;
            FactorySchema<?, ?, Session> schema = DateTime.SCHEMA;
            if (v.elementAt(0) instanceof lotus.domino.DateRange)   // at moment: never
                schema = DateRange.SCHEMA;
            else {  // Workaround for Vector of DateRange-s
                while (true) {
                    int sz = v.size(), i;
                    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
                        if (v.elementAt(i) != null)
                            break;
                    if (i < sz)
                        break;
                    vGIV = getDelegate().getItemValue(name);
                    if (vGIV.size() != sz * 2)
                        break;
                    for (i = 0; i < sz * 2; i++)
                        if (!(vGIV.elementAt(i) instanceof lotus.domino.DateTime))
                            break;
                    if (i < sz * 2)
                        break;
                    Vector<lotus.domino.DateRange> aux = new Vector<lotus.domino.DateRange>(sz);
                    lotus.domino.Session rawsession = toLotus(Factory.getSession());
                    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
                        lotus.domino.DateTime dts = (lotus.domino.DateTime) vGIV.elementAt(2 * i);
                        lotus.domino.DateTime dte = (lotus.domino.DateTime) vGIV.elementAt(2 * i + 1);
                        lotus.domino.DateRange dr = rawsession.createDateRange(dts, dte);
                        aux.add(dr);
                    }
                    v = aux;
                    schema = DateRange.SCHEMA;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return (Vector<org.openntf.domino.Base<?>>) fromLotusAsVector(v, schema, getAncestorSession());
        } catch (NotesException e) {
            while (mayBeMime) {
                MIMEEntity entity = this.getMIMEEntity(name);
                if (entity == null)
                    break;
                Object mim = null;
                try {
                    mim = Documents.getItemValueMIME(this, name, entity);
                } finally {
                    closeMIMEEntities(false, name);
                }
                if (mim == null)
                    break;
                Vector<?> v;
                if (mim instanceof Vector)
                    v = (Vector<Object>) mim;
                else if (mim instanceof Collection)
                    v = new Vector<Object>((Collection<Object>) mim);
                else if (mim.getClass().isArray())
                    v = (Vector<Object>) Arrays.asList((Object[]) mim);
                else
                    break;
                int sz = v.size(), i;
                for (i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
                    Object o = v.elementAt(i);
                    if (o == null)
                        break;
                    if ((!(o instanceof DateTime)) && (!(o instanceof DateRange)))
                        break;
                }
                if (i < sz)
                    break;
                return (Vector<org.openntf.domino.Base<?>>) v;
            }
            DominoUtils.handleException(e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (vGIV != null)
                Base.s_recycle(vGIV);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late, but this may help someone later on as an alternative.

```
  doc.getFirstItem("dateAdded").getDateTimeValue().getLocalTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated the IBM example with something a little simpler that returns a Java Date data type.  I rarely have encountered date fields with multiple values.

```
protected Date getDateValue(String fieldname, Document doc, boolean getenddate) throws NotesException{
    Vector times = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray(fieldname);
    Object time = null;
    Date date = null;

    if(times != null){
        time = times.elementAt(0);

        if (time.getClass().getName().endsWith("DateTime")) {
            date = ((DateTime) time).toJavaDate();
        }
        else if(time.getClass().getName().endsWith("DateRange")) {
            if(getenddate == true){
                date = ((DateRange) time).getEndDateTime().toJavaDate();
            }else{
                date = ((DateRange) time).getStartDateTime().toJavaDate();
            }
        }
    }

    return date; 
}
```